# Creating an Alias in Windows

Tags: batch-file, cmd, alias, phinx

I have the command below.

```
php public/index.php phinx setup
```

Is there a way in which I could simplify this in Windows? I was wanting to create a shortcut/alias as shown below.

```
phinx setup
```

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: I ended up creating a C:\bin\phinx.cmd with "php public/index.php phinx %1". Now works like a charm via my IDE.

Comment: Or $ echo php public/index.php phinx %1 > C:\bin\phinx.cmd

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is what you are looking for:

```
doskey test=cd \a_very_long_path\test
```

You can find more information [here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms682057%28v=vs.85%29.aspx).